# Error while reading File using loop

Tags: java, binary-tree

```
public class FileIO {
    public static BinaryTree Level1;
    public static BinaryTree Level2;
    static BinaryTree Level3;
    static BinaryTree Val;

    public FileIO () {
       Level1 = new BinaryTree ();
       Level2 = new BinaryTree ();
       Level3 = new BinaryTree ();
       Val = new BinaryTree ();
    }

    public static void Refill () throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner Lev1 = new Scanner (new File ("C:\\Users\\Shandana\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ScrambledWords\\Level1.txt"));
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner (new File ("C:\\Users\\Shandana\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ScrambledWords\\Level1 Dictionary.txt"));

        while (Lev1.hasNextLine() && input1.hasNextLine())  {
             Level1.Insert(Lev1.nextLine(), input1.nextLine());
        }

        Lev1.close();
        input1.close();
    }
}
```

This code shows nullpointerexception() when trying to insert words from a file into a binary tree. It works absolutely fine if I do not use loop but without loop it won't run until end of file.

Can someone please help me understand why is this error coming and how can I resolve it.

Comment: remove static modifier from your method Refill and test it again... or you make everything static (also the constructor of Level1 or you do not....)

Comment: I copied the same code in main and than ran it but it still did not work. But I still tried to do it without static and it gave me tons more error :/

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1670)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1538)
 at scrambledwords.FileIO.Refill(FileIO.java:70)
 at scrambledwords.ScrambledWords.main(ScrambledWords.java:44)
C:\Users\Shandana\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove static from the method as well as the member variables.

`public static void Refill () throws FileNotFoundException` change to `public void Refill () throws FileNotFoundException`

Then call this method by `new FileIO().Refill()`

I would also do

```
if(Lev1!=null&&input1!=null) {
    while (Lev1.hasNextLine() && input1.hasNextLine())  {
         Level1.Insert(Lev1.nextLine(), input1.nextLine());
    }
}
if(Lev1!=null) {
    Lev1.close();
}

if(input1!=null) {
    input1.close();
}
```

Comment: It gave me illeagal state exception

Comment: Where ? Please remove all the static what you have in this IOFile class.

Comment: I did...It says scanner closed

Comment: Can you give you stack trace. please

Comment: Nothing is working!! I guess the problem is with the loop but I can't figure out what. I'm a beginner programmer and I have no idea how to handle these errors

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1670)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1538)
 at scrambledwords.FileIO.Refill(FileIO.java:70)
 at scrambledwords.ScrambledWords.main(ScrambledWords.java:44)
C:\Users\Shandana\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Comment: If you get the error in line 70 of your code, you did not show us what you are actually running. Please update your question accordingly. Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with the code you actually have, or nobody will be able to help you.